# Bluetooth activation fails due to “bthHFSrv.dll” missing

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I am trying to activate Bluetooth on my PC (Windows 10 OS), but I find myself unable to do so since there is no activation button (it has been there before but it has recently disappeared). Is there a way to get it back and what do I need to do?

[image: Screenshot.]

I have tried searching for solution online and I found [this article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-enabledisable-bluetooth-using-a-command/30cf18e2-e9bf-48ab-b247-85973f2eff38) about turning it on using cmd, and, after following instructions, error message appears which says “The specified service does not exist as an installed service.”

Googling it, I found out that I’m missing the `bthHFSrv.dll` library (it doesn't exist in my PC, I checked in system32). So, any solutions?

Is there a trusted website from where I can download the library?

Comment: Look in Device Manager. Any red or yellow X beside the Bluetooth device?   Try reinstalling the Bluetooth driver.

Comment: @John Hi, there seems to be [no bluetooth drivers](https://ibb.co/gj6XtWL) in Device Manager.

Comment: Your Bluetooth card appears to have failed and needs to be replaced.

Comment: @John I have resolved the problem, thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Thanks.  I have not had happen what you describe. I have had a bluetooth daughter card fail and replacement was the only way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully resolved the problem.

It turned out to be a specific Embedded Controller (EC) failure. In order to solve this, please check whether your BIOS is updated to the newest version (PC manufacturers usually have automatic driver updaters on their sites). Of course, there is possibility that your Bluetooth card failed, as mentioned in the comments above, or that the problem is of some other sort.